Audio Recorder in React
Requirement: I am trying to build a real time audio recorder in react, in which i need the recorded audio chunks in blob audio/wav format.
Problem: I have used react-mic, navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true }), react-media-recorder, But the chunks i am reciving from them are not playable maybe those are corrupt chunk.
I want to get audio chunks in audio/wav formart

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
